# joining four tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables that I'm wondering If I should join, the tables are structured as follows:

```
members                                                          

member_id    login    


permissions

K_id    member_id   date


kcontent

K_id    id    content  


ktitle

K_id          title
```

What I'm trying to do is, that for a specific member (member_id)....get each K_id that each member is linked to, order them by date DESC, and then get the content from kcontent ordered by id and title from ktitle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should.

Try something along these lines:

```
SELECT a.member_id, b.date, d.title, c.content
FROM members as a
JOIN permissions as b
ON b.member_id = a.member_id
JOIN kcontent as c
ON c.k_id = b.k_id
JOIN ktitle as d
ON d.k_id = b.k_id
WHERE a.member_id = {inputMemberId}
ORDER BY b.date, d.k_id, d.title
```

Comment: hmm this is returning an empty result for some reason

Comment: You could try an outer join instead of inner join if the data is empty sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM 
PERMISSIONS INNER JOIN KCONTENT
ON PERMISSIONS.K_ID = KCONTENT.K_ID
INNER JOIN KTITLE
ON KCONTENT.K_ID = KTITLE.K_ID
INNER JOIN MEMEBRS
ON MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID = PERMISSIONS.MEMBER_ID
WHERE MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID = ###
ORDER BY PERMISSIONS.DATE, MEMBERS.MEMBER_ID
```

Comment: wouldn't this need a where clause for a specific member_id